# mysql function create statement throwing error

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

```
CREATE FUNCTION INPolygon(pnt varchar(50),poly varchar(500)) RETURNS int(1)
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE x, y, p1x, p1y, p2x, p2y float(20, 16) DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE counter,i INT DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE touches float(20,16);
DECLARE intersect int DEFAULT 0;
set counter = substrCount(poly,"#") + 1;
set x = trim(strSplit(pnt,',',1));
set y = trim(strSplit(pnt,',',2));
while i <= counter DO
set p1x = strSplit(strSplit(poly,'#',i), ',', 1);
set p1y = strSplit(strSplit(poly,'#',i), ',', 2);
set p2x = strSplit(strSplit(poly, '#', i+1), ',', 1);
set p2y = strSplit(strSplit(poly, '#', i+1), ',', 2);
IF ((x = p1x AND y = p1y) OR (x = p2x AND y = p2y)) THEN
RETURN 1;
END IF;
IF (p1y = p2y and p1y = y and x > MIN(p1x, p2x) and x < MAX(p1x, p2x))  THEN
return 1;
END IF;
IF (y > MIN(p1y, p2y) AND y <= MAX(p1y,p2y) AND x <= MAX(p1x, p2x) AND p1y != p2y) THEN
set touches = (y - p1y) * (x - p1x) / (p2y - p1y) + x;
IF touches = x THEN
return 1;
END IF;
IF p1x = p2x OR x <= touches THEN
set intersect = intersect+1;
END IF;
END IF;
END WHILE;
RETURN intersect % 2;
END
```

I is throwing an error saying

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' p2x) and x < MAX(p1x, p2x)) THEN return 1; END IF; IF (y > MIN(p1y, p2y) AND y' at line 19

Comment: How does the error message continue? The interesting part is missing.

Comment: to use near ' p2x) and x < MAX(p1x, p2x)) THEN return 1; END IF; IF (y > MIN(p1y, p2y) AND y' at line 19

Comment: Maybe it happens because you try to cast a string to float in set x...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `min()` and `max()` like that. Use [LEAST()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) and [GREATEST()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) to get the lowest and highest value of 2 columns. Change the segments where you use `MIN()` from

```
MIN(p1y, p2y)
```

to

```
LEAST(p1y, p2x)
```

and

```
MAX(p1y, p2y)
```

to

```
GREATEST(p1y, p2y)
```

Comment: +1 and accept for your response i am fighting with it from morning thanks